# Where to keep the queries?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In ArticleController I have:

```
$em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a WHERE a.showing = 1 ORDER BY createdAt DESC";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);

$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $query, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    10/*limit per page*/
);
```

And in AdminController I have:

```
    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a WHERE a.showing = 1 ORDER BY createdAt DESC";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $results = $query->getResults();
```

So I have duplicate:

```
$em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$dql   = "SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a WHERE a.showing = 1 ORDER BY createdAt DESC";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
```

The results from the database should be kept in the Repositorium, but what if it is query without results/executions?

Where to keep query without results/executions according to the rules of correct programming?

I will use this query in several places, including the services.

Comment: Repositories are still a good place for them. Slightly related - [CQRS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Comment: In general - you should keep them in [data mappers](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). But since you are using Doctrine, that is kinda not the most viable option. So, repository it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to store queries in [Entity Repository](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/repository.html) classes. You can easily reuse it in your controllers or inject it to your services. You can implement different methods to return result set, a Query object or whatever you need.

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllOrderedByNameQuery()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is query without results, so your example is bad. I have to have only query.

Comment: Adjusted my sample. You can return anything you need in your repository method. It's just a right place where data fetching logic should live.

Comment: ...instead of controllers, which should only dispatch any action to services to keep them testable

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the design pattern Repository return only collections?

Comment: Fowler suggest to use Repository pattern as a collection-like interface to access domain objects. But in practice repository class can return a single entity, a collection, null, array of scalar values (when using an alternative hydration mode, e.g. to get a COUNT query result) and QueryBuilder/Query objects (for Symfony form's EntityType, pagination, etc.). Just keep the data retrieving logic in repository classes to reuse it and avoid query code duplication.